# NGINX - Directive to Allow iPhone's IP address for accessing wordpress login page (mysite.com/wp-login.php), and Deny all other IP addresses

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy, blacklist

**MY ENVIRONMENT:**

I am running a LEMP server which is working and running wordpress quite properly. As of now, I have my wordpress web login (www.mysite/wp-login.php) blacklisted by all IP addresses EXCEPT any IP on my LAN with the following directive:

```
server {
    # Allow LAN only on wp-login page (www.mysite.com/wp-login.php)
    location ~ /wp-login.php {
        allow 192.168.1.0/24;
        deny all;
    }
```

This directive sucessfully blocks all internet traffic to "mywebsite.com/wp-login.php", which is the wordpress admin login page.
In other words, with this directive set, I can access the wordpress login page anywhere on my internal LAN, but the directive denys any outside internet traffic from seeing the "mywebsite.com/wp-login.php" page. GREAT!

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**,

is to whitelist the IP address of my phone, so that I can access the wordpress login page from my phone's IP address, while still blocking any other outside internet traffic. To do so, I go to [www.whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org) on my phone, copy the ip address that it gives me, then modify the previous directive to look like the following:

```
server {
    # Allow LAN and CellPhone access to to wp-login page (www.mysite.com/wp-login.php)
    location ~ /wp-login.php {
        allow 77.232.28.46; # my phones ip address as shown on whatsmyip.org
        allow 192.168.1.0/24;
        deny all;
    }
```

HOWEVER,

after reloading nginx, I still cannot access the wp-login (wordpress login) page from my phone.

**MY QUESTION IS:**

Using NGINX, How can I properly whitelist my phones IP address, while blacklisting everything else access to the wordpress login page locate at *[www.mysite.com/wp-login.php](http://www.mysite.com/wp-login.php)* ?

**FOR REFERENCE:**

Below is my **NGINX.CONF** file:

```
# This is the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file for Danrancan's LEMP server
#
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
load_module /usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so;
 
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}
 
http {
    ##
    # Mod Security
    ##
    modsecurity on;
    #modsecurity off;
    modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;
 
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##
    client_max_body_size 512M;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    server_tokens off;
 
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;
 
# Create a custom Nginx log format called netdata that includes information about request_time, and upstream_response_time, measured in seconds with millisecond resolution.
log_format netdata '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
              '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
              '$request_length $request_time $upstream_response_time '
              '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
 
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
 
    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##
 
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;   #SSL session cache
    ssl_session_timeout 1h;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
 
    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##
 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 
    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##
 
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        text/javascript
        text/xml;
 
    # Extra Http Header response to determine whether a request is being served from the cache
    #add_header Fastcgi-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
 
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
 
    upstream local_php {
        server unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
 
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/perfect-forward-secrecy.conf;
 
    ##
    # Harden nginx against DDOS. #noted from www.pestmeester.nl
    ##
 
    client_header_timeout 10;
    # For good security, set client_body_timeout to 10. For uploading large files, set to higher.
    client_body_timeout   10;
    keepalive_timeout     10;
    send_timeout          10;
}
```

and my **VIRTUAL HOST CONFIG:**

```
# Danrancan's Virtual host config for /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com.conf
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    ###
    # SSL (From Mozilla Config Generator: Modern Configuration)
    ###

    # Add Strict Transport Security Response Header with "always Paramater", to help prevent MITM attacks.
    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains" always;

    ## Prevent click jacking by adding an X-Frame header

    # Add X-Frame-Options header to nginx with the following line:
    add_header x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN" always;

    # Add a content security policy header
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';";

    # Secure MIME Types with X-Content-Type-Options. Below line adds the X-Fram-Options header in Nginx.
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    # Enable X-XSS-Protection header in Nginx
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin";
    add_header Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(),midi=(),sync-xhr=(),microphone=(),camera=(),magnetometer=(),gyroscope=(),fullscreen=(self),payment=()";

    # Path to signerd certificate + Intermediate certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem; # Managed by admin
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; # Managed by admin

    # Perfect Forward Secrecy Diffie-Hellman 4096 parameters
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/private/dhparams4096.pem; # Managed by admin

    # Include "perfect-forward-secrecy.conf" file in this virtual host. NOTE: No need to do this, as its already included in the nginx.conf file, so you should comment this out.
    #include /etc/nginx/perfect-forward-secrecy.conf; # Managed by admin

    # Modern SSL configuration with OCSP stapling turned on
    #ssl_protocols TLSv1.3; # commented out because its already in the nginx.conf file
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
    # Verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/chain.pem; # Managed by admin

    server_name mysite.com  www.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/mysite.com;

    # Error & Access Logs
    #error_log /var/www/mysite.com.logs/error.log error;
    #access_log /var/www/mysite.com.logs/access.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.access.log netdata;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.error.log warn;

    # This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Only allow access of /admin via internal IP
    location ^~ /admin {
        allow 192.168.1.0/24;
        deny all;
        error_page 403 =444;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    }

    # Allow local only to wp-login page
    location ~ /wp-login.php {
        allow 192.168.1.0/24;
        deny all;
        error_page 403 =444;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Cache Static Files For As Long As Possible
    location ~*\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }

    # Security Settings For Better Privacy Deny Hidden Files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Disallow PHP In Upload Folder
    location /wp-content/uploads/ {
        location ~ \.php$ {
        deny all;
        }
    }

    # Pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # Below was Added from recommended by pestmeester.nl
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because your phone IP changes regularly… you'd better look into something like VPN (there are various VPN clients available for smartphones).

Comment: Regardless, I still have other gadets with a static ip address that I would like to allow from the internet. So even if the iphone doesnt work, my ip address at work needs to be whitelisted as well.

Comment: Is your WP site on your local, *internal* LAN?

Comment: My WP site is on the WAN, but I can utilize it over the LAN by puting my local IP adddress of the server into my hosts file on my client computer and then typing the www.mysite.com address which then would point to my local ip address of the server over the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work.
Since it is not, it seems that for some reason nginx doesn't see your phone IP as a match to what you have configured.

It sounds like your WP box is running on a private network (because of the `192.168.1.0/` IP addresses you mentioned).

When you connect to the WP box from the internet, is it going through a router with port forwarding/NAT?

First thing I would do is just `tail` your nginx access log (`access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;`) when trying to access with your iphone and see what is reported.

If the request is coming through a proxy/reverse-proxy you may need to make sure the proxy is adding `X-Forwarded-For` to pass along the remote (iphone) ip address.  The request to nginx/wp would be coming from the proxy IP and there would be a header `X-Forwarded-For` added to the request containing the original remote address.

When nginx is used this way you need to use nginx's realip module...something like:

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 192.168.1.1;  # proxy ip
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html